# MongoDB not showing the Data sent or created from the Model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have been working on  CRUD app with express and mongoDB using mongoose, for some reason all the data created on model schema is not being reflected on MongoDB. I am not sure what I am getting wrong but I am asking someone to help me with why the data created on model is not showing in the mongoDB as if I go postman and excute get method for http:/localhost:5001/jobs it gives me the output shown below. Also below are all my files to get your guidance.

sample data posted on POSTMAN using post router:

```
{
     "username": "test",
     "job_title": "DevOps",
     "job_comp_image": "https://pixabay.com/images/id-1869401/",
     "job_comp_name": "Training Academy",
     "job_description":"Web Developer",
     "job_location": "City",
     "job_field": "IT",
     "job_closing_date": "2021-11-07T04:11:08.924Z",
     "job_date_created" : "2021-11-07T04:11:08.924Z"
}
```

POSTMAN GET output after a sample job was posted:

```
        "_id": "618bb690fbef67502a29854b",
        "username": "test",
        "job_closing_date": "2021-11-10T12:09:52.427Z",
        "job_date_created": "2021-11-10T12:09:52.427Z",
        "createdAt": "2021-11-10T12:09:52.428Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-11-10T12:09:52.428Z",
        "__v": 0
```

**jobs.model.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;


const jobsiteSchema = new Schema ({

    username: String,
    job_title: String ,
    job_comp_image: String,
    job_comp_name: String,
    job_description: String,
    job_location:  String,
    job_field: String ,
    job_closing_date: { type: Date, default: Date.now},
    job_date_created: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
}, {
    timestamps: true,
});  

const Job =  mongoose.model("Job", jobsiteSchema) ;

module.exports = Job;
```

**jobs.js**

```
const router = require('express').Router();
let Job = require('../models/jobs.model');

router.route('/').get((req, res) => {
  Job.find()
    .then(jobs => res.json(jobs))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
});

router.route('/add').post((req, res) => {

  const username = req.body.username;
  const jobTitle = req.body.job_title;
  const JobCompImage = req.body.job_comp_image;
  const JobCompName = req.body.job_comp_name;
  const JobDescription = req.body.job_description;
  const JobLocation = req.body.job_location;
  const JobField = req.body.job_field;
  const JobClosingDate = req.body.job_closing_date ;
  const JobPostingDate = Date.parse(req.body.job_date_created) ;
  

  console.log(username)
  console.log(jobTitle)
  console.log(JobCompImage)
  console.log(JobCompName)
  console.log(JobDescription)
  console.log(JobLocation)
  console.log(JobField)
  console.log(JobClosingDate)
  console.log(JobPostingDate)

  // Create new Job using the fields above
  const newJob = new Job({
    username:username,
    jobTitle : jobTitle,
    JobCompImage : JobCompImage,
    JobCompName: JobCompName,
    JobDescription: JobDescription,
    JobLocation: JobLocation,
    JobField : JobField,
    JobClosingDate : JobClosingDate,
    JobPostingDate : JobPostingDate
  });

  //Save the new Job
  newJob.save()
    .then(() => res.json('Job added!'))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
});

router.route('/:id').get((req, res) => {
  Job.findById(req.params.id)
    .then(job => res.json(job))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
});

router.route('/:id').delete((req, res) => {
    Job.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id)
    .then(() => res.json('Job deleted.'))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
});

router.route('/update/:id').post((req, res) => {
    Job.findById(req.params.id)
    .then(job => {
    

     // username = req.body.username;
      job.jobTitle = req.body.job_title;
      job.JobCompImage = req.body.job_comp_image;
      job.JobCompName = req.body.job_comp_name
      job.JobDescription = req.body.job_description;
      job.JobLocation = req.body.job_location;
      job.JobField = req.body.job_field;
      job.JobClosingDate = req.body.job_closing_date ;

      job.save()
        .then(() => res.json('Job updated!!!'))
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
    })
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
});

module.exports = router;
```

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const path = require("path");

require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();

const jobsRouter = require('./routes/jobs');
const usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

// ... other app.use middleware 
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "backend", "build")));

const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
mongoose.connect(uri, 
                  { useNewUrlParser: true, 
                    //useCreateIndex: true,
                    useUnifiedTopology: true 
                 }
);
const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once('open', () => {
  console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully");
})



app.use('/jobs', jobsRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

const port = process.env.PORT || 5001;

// Right before your app.listen(), add this:
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "backend", "build", "index.html"));
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port: ${port}`);
})
```

Comment: This is a very basic error. Please debug it properly before asking it directly to SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's due to wrong variable names: Your schema has variable names defined in the underscore case and you are passing data in MongoDB in camelCase.

As `username` matches you get that value stored. All the timestamp have default values so you get those values too.

```
const jobsiteSchema = new Schema ({

    username: String,
    job_title: String ,
    job_comp_image: String,
    job_comp_name: String,
    job_description: String,
    job_location:  String,
    job_field: String ,
    job_closing_date: { type: Date, default: Date.now},
    job_date_created: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
}, {
    timestamps: true,
})
```

Change your routing hander to following:

```
router.route('/add').post((req, res) => {
    const newJob = new Job(req.body);

    //Save the new Job
    newJob.save()
        .then(() => res.json('Job added!'))
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
    });
```

It's ideal to add validation of the req body before storing it to DB.